# build failed in libgdx

Tags: java, gradle, libgdx

i made a libgdx project using the libgdx setup jar with the following configurations

```
{
  name: 'mfgdx',
  package: com.coder,
  Game_class: MainGame,
  destination: $userhome
  Subprojects: [Desktop,html]
  extensions: [tools,box2d,ashley]
```

but i got an error

```
BUILD FAILED in 32s
```

what did i do wrong, and how do i fix it?

I have tried removing android from subprojects and also tried with no extensions, but the problem never seems to go

Comment: Can you show the comolete build log?

Comment: i would but it is extremely long and stack overflow is not allowing to include that

Comment: Did you try to edit your question and add it in a code block? the limitation is only for comments.

Comment: I recommend using gdx-liftoff instead of the official setup jar. The libgdx team is planning to switch over to gdx-liftoff at some point. https://github.com/tommyettinger/gdx-liftoff